# Вставка значения из списка в шаблон

Tags: django

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть список из которого я беру значения в модель. Когда я создаю объект по это модели, выпадающий список работает отлично, я получаю значения 'Вход', 'Выход'. Но когда пытаюсь вставить это значение в шаблон получаю 'Enter', 'Exit'. Подскажите, что я делаю не так?

**list.py**

```
list = (
('Enter','Вход'),
('Exit','Выход')
)
```

**models.py**

```
class Object(models.Model):
     object = models.CharField('Объект', choices=list, default='Enter', blank=True, max_length=10)
```

**template.html**

```
<li>
{{ Object.object }}
</li>
```

Comment: а если `{{ Object.get_object_display }}` ?

Comment: Отлично! Спасибо, это решение!